# Replace Images in Asset catalog programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to replace images from server to Asset catalog via programmatically (iOS)?

Comment: I think you can not do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image asset add in the app bundle. and You can't change anything in the app bundle at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change images from an asset catalogue programatically as they are baked into the app. You can, however, use something like [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) to load images from a URL which is probably what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change anything inside NSBundle. So you can put your image in DocumentDirectory.And make sure your document directory should not sync with iCloud.