# How to change the color of `color set` programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicolor

There is any way to change the color of `color set` programmatically.

[image]

[image]

I use theme color in Xcode and now I want this color come from API. Anyone can solve my problem.

I search this on the net but all tell us how to make `color set` and how to use it but I want how to change this color during run time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we use Assets Catalog Colors Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397680/how-can-we-use-assets-catalog-colors-sets)

Comment: all tell how to make color set and then use it.. but i want change it during run time

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat, I had this question too but could not find an answer. But when looking at the same question for image assets, the answer was that the asset files are part of the bundle and can not be modified at run time. [Replace images in asset catalog programatically ios] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724238/replace-images-in-asset-catalog-programatically-ios)

Comment: @Bijender did you ever find or figure out a solution?

Comment: @Smartcat sorry bro.. not..

Comment: So if we need to decide colour schemes from back end,we can't use colorset and we need to creat dedicated Theme Manager class

Comment: @Anees yes bro.. we cant use colorset when we want to change color from the backend.